# how to change display layout at frontend using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap-4

hi m getting categories from db in this way: https://ibb.co/3WtryYK and I wants to show them in this way https://ibb.co/NnmBKkm    ,   I need a scenario like conditional statement or loop and select 2 grids that one category show in one grid and the oher in another

code:

```
   @foreach($categories as $category)
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-lg-4 m-l-r-auto">
                <!-- block1 -->

                <div class="block1 hov-img-zoom pos-relative m-b-30">
                    <img src="{{ asset('/images/frontend_images/banner-02.jpg') }}" alt="IMG-BENNER">

                    <div class="block1-wrapbtn w-size2">
                        <!-- Button -->
                        <a href="#" class="flex-c-m size2 m-text2 bg3 hov1 trans-0-4">
                            {{ ucwords($category->category_name) }}
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <!-- block1 -->
                <div class="block1 hov-img-zoom pos-relative m-b-30">
                    <img src="{{ asset('/images/frontend_images/banner-05.jpg') }}" alt="IMG-BENNER">

                    <div class="block1-wrapbtn w-size2">
                        <!-- Button -->
                        <a href="#" class="flex-c-m size2 m-text2 bg3 hov1 trans-0-4">
                            Sunglasses
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            @endforeach
```

complete code:

```
    <section class="banner bgwhite p-t-40 p-b-40">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            @foreach($categories as $category)
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-lg-4 m-l-r-auto">
                <!-- block1 -->

                <div class="block1 hov-img-zoom pos-relative m-b-30">
                    <img src="{{ asset('/images/frontend_images/banner-02.jpg') }}" alt="IMG-BENNER">

                    <div class="block1-wrapbtn w-size2">
                        <!-- Button -->
                        <a href="#" class="flex-c-m size2 m-text2 bg3 hov1 trans-0-4">
                            {{ ucwords($category->category_name) }}
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <!-- block1 -->
                <div class="block1 hov-img-zoom pos-relative m-b-30">
                    <img src="{{ asset('/images/frontend_images/banner-05.jpg') }}" alt="IMG-BENNER">

                    <div class="block1-wrapbtn w-size2">
                        <!-- Button -->
                        <a href="#" class="flex-c-m size2 m-text2 bg3 hov1 trans-0-4">
                            Sunglasses
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            @endforeach

            <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-lg-4 m-l-r-auto">
                <!-- block1 -->
                <div class="block1 hov-img-zoom pos-relative m-b-30">
                    <img src="{{ asset('/images/frontend_images/banner-03.jpg') }}" alt="IMG-BENNER">

                    <div class="block1-wrapbtn w-size2">
                        <!-- Button -->
                        <a href="#" class="flex-c-m size2 m-text2 bg3 hov1 trans-0-4">
                            Watches
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- block1 -->
                <div class="block1 hov-img-zoom pos-relative m-b-30">
                    <img src="{{ asset('/images/frontend_images/banner-07.jpg') }}" alt="IMG-BENNER">

                    <div class="block1-wrapbtn w-size2">
                        <!-- Button -->
                        <a href="#" class="flex-c-m size2 m-text2 bg3 hov1 trans-0-4">
                            Footerwear
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-lg-4 m-l-r-auto">
                <!-- block1 -->
                <div class="block1 hov-img-zoom pos-relative m-b-30">
                    <img src="{{ asset('/images/frontend_images/banner-04.jpg') }}" alt="IMG-BENNER">

                    <div class="block1-wrapbtn w-size2">
                        <!-- Button -->
                        <a href="#" class="flex-c-m size2 m-text2 bg3 hov1 trans-0-4">
                            Bags
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- block2 -->
                <div class="block2 wrap-pic-w pos-relative m-b-30">
                    <img src="{{ asset('/images/frontend_images/icons/bg-01.jpg') }}" alt="IMG">

                    <div class="block2-content sizefull ab-t-l flex-col-c-m">
                        <h4 class="m-text4 t-center w-size3 p-b-8">
                            Sign up & get 20% off
                        </h4>

                        <p class="t-center w-size4">
                            Be the frist to know about the latest fashion news and get exclu-sive offers
                        </p>

                        <div class="w-size2 p-t-25">
                            <!-- Button -->
                            <a href="#" class="flex-c-m size2 bg4 bo-rad-23 hov1 m-text3 trans-0-4">
                                Sign Up
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Blade solution:**

Based on further explantation:

```
<style>
.small{
    height: 300px;
}
.big{
    height: 700px;
}
</style>

@foreach($categories as $key => $category)
<div class="col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-lg-4 m-l-r-auto">
    <!-- block1 -->

    <div class="block1 hov-img-zoom pos-relative m-b-30 {{($key % 2 == 0 ? 'big' : 'small')}}">
        <img src="{{ asset('/images/frontend_images/banner-02.jpg') }}" alt="IMG-BENNER">

        <div class="block1-wrapbtn w-size2">
            <!-- Button -->
            <a href="#" class="flex-c-m size2 m-text2 bg3 hov1 trans-0-4">
                {{ ucwords($category->category_name) }}
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
@endforeach
```

The `@if` in this case does an odd/even selection based on keys of your categories. If you only want the first two or something change the `@if` to `@if($key < 2)`.

---

**JS/jQuery solution**
I'm not sure what your question is about, but I guess it's about displaying cards stacked. If your question is about something else please clarify your question.

I think you're looking for a JavaScript solution to stack cards like that. Something like:

- [Masonry](https://masonry.desandro.com) (JavaScript)
- [Salvattore](https://salvattore.js.org) (jQuery)

Comment: I need a scenario like conditional statement or loop and select 2 grids that one category show in one grid and the other in another ,,, I have updated the question

Comment: I need something like this but should u prefer to tell me that how can I arrange my code to get the results like it

Comment: A little initiative doesn't hurt, but I have modified the code example.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel is not responsible for frontend code. You have to check in CSS files.
Maybe you have to set at least 3 different grids.

Good luck.

Comment: I know that Laravel is not responsible for frontend code, but here in html code is in Laravel, I need a scenario like conditional statement or loop and select 2 grids that one category show in one grid and the oher in another